# Точки для переключения слайдера не выравниваются по правому краю

Tags: css, html5, position, выравнивание

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чём проблема, вроде все позиции заданы правильно, а они  не выравниваются по правому краю и не расположены друг под другом.

```css
.portfolio-slider{
 position: relative;
}

.portfolio-slider .slick-dots{
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 right: 20%;
 transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

.slick-dots li{
 margin: 5px 0;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-slider">
    <div><a href="#"><img src="img/Rectangle 136.png" alt=""></a></div>
    <div><a href="#"><img src="img/Rectangle 136.png" alt=""></a></div>
    <div><a href="#"><img src="img/Rectangle 136.png" alt=""></a></div>
   </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Загрузи картинки на сервис

Comment: загрузите полностью ваш рабочий слайдер поможем

Comment: Возможно проблема в том что вы задали right: 20%, а не right: 20px

Comment: Насчёт "right" да, исправлено. Но у меня они всё равно размещены в ряд, а не друг под другом.